# ScalaFX When dragging the mouse too quickly on canvas, the drawn line appears as a series of dots rather than a continuous line

Tags: scala, scalafx, scalafxml

```
package com.doodlr.view

import javafx.fxml.FXML
import scalafx.scene.input.MouseEvent
import scalafx.Includes.jfxCanvas2sfx
import scalafx.scene.canvas.Canvas
import scalafxml.core.macros.sfxml
import scalafx.scene.paint.{Color, CycleMethod, LinearGradient, Stop}
import scalafx.scene.shape.Rectangle
import com.doodlr.Main

@sfxml
class CanvasDoodleController (private val canvas: Canvas) {
  val gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D
  def handleDrag(event: MouseEvent): Unit = {
    val x = event.getX
    val y = event.getY
    println(s"Mouse dragged at coordinates: ($x, $y)")
    gc.setFill(Color.Black)
    gc.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5)
  }



  def handleClick(event: MouseEvent): Unit = {
    if (event.clickCount > 1) {
      resetCanvas()
    }
  }
  // Function to reset the entire canvas to white
  private def resetCanvas(): Unit = {
    // Clear the entire canvas
    gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width.value, canvas.height.value)

    // Fill the canvas with white color
    gc.setFill(Color.White)
    gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width.value, canvas.height.value)
  }
}
```

When dragging the mouse too quickly on a ScalaFX canvas, the drawn line appears as a series of dots rather than a continuous line. I just want user to able to draw normally. thank you

Comment: That handler merely registers the event that was created by JVM's framework. If handler emits an event every once in a while, it doesn't reflect every single pixel that your mouse traveled. It's on you to e.g. store state that mouse was clicked but not released, and that the previous pixel was `(x,y)` and so you should draw a line from the previous known position to the current one as an approximation. The faster you move your mouse the more visible it becomes that IO input is a discrete process and that you should consider that in your design.